# Differentiation under the integral sign using Fubini.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, partial-derivative, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let's consider a function
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}
$$
And suppose it is smooth, then for a given $M>0$ and $y\geq 0$, according to Fubini's theorem, we have that
$$
\int_{-M}^M\partial_yf(x,y)dx=\frac{d}{dy}\int_0^y\int_{-M}^M\partial_yf(x,y)dxdy=\frac{d}{dy}\int_{-M}^M\int_0^y\partial_yf(x,y)dydx=\frac{d}{dy}\int_{-M}^Mf(x,y)dx
$$
Then when $M\to+\infty$ if the limit exists we would have that
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}\partial_yf(x,y)dx=\frac{d}{dy}\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y)dx
$$
I would like to know if the reasoning above is correct, any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that you can exchange the order of $d/dy$ and $\lim\limits_{M\to\infty}$?

Comment: That's what I would like to know if we can do

Comment: @QiyuWen I think you need the improper integral to converge uniformly

Comment: What does that mean?